# get all records from two tables but from second table only the ones that are not in first

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am creating a MUD game.In that I have two quest tables, there is an active_quests and a completed_quests. There are a lot of customised reports that my players can see.

In one such report, after they choose a bunch of quest_ids, I want to show them their scores/status for that quest. The report should be such that I only want to show the score from the active_quests table if it exists in that table, else from completed_quests.

So the query (**in pseudo-code**) I need is something like:

```
select active_quests.*
from active_quests
where quest_id in (<list_of_quest_ids>)
and player_id = <player_id>

UNION

select completed_quests.*
from completed_quests
where quest_id NOT in (<the_results_we_got_above>)
and quest_id in (<list_of_quests>)
and player_id = <player_id>
```

But I have no idea how to write this :(

Comment: How you get  the <list_of_quest_ids>?   ... is a subselect ..?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your  is a subselect like

```
  select quest_id from you_quest_table where your_col = your_val
```

you could use  somethings like

```
    select active_quests.*
    from active_quests
    where quest_id in (
      select quest_id from you_quest_table where your_col = your_val
      )
    and player_id = <player_id>

    UNION

    select completed_quests.*
    from completed_quests
    where quest_id NOT in (

    select active_quests.*
    from active_quests
    where quest_id in (
      select quest_id from you_quest_table where your_col = your_val)
    and player_id = <player_id>

    )
    and quest_id in (
       select quest_id from you_quest_table where your_col = your_val
    )
    and player_id = <player_id>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, quest_ids are a predefined comma-separated list of ids that I get from another page.

Comment: which server side language do you are using ?  and update your question with a sample of this quest_id  list

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
select aq.*
from active_quests aq
where aq.quest_id in (<list_of_quest_ids>) and
      aq.player_id = <player_id>
union all
select cq.*
from completed_quests
where not exists (select 1
                  from activequests aq
                  where aq.player_id = cq.player_id and
                        aq.quest_id = cq.quest_id
                 )
      cq.quest_id in (<list_of_quests>) and
      cq.player_id = <player_id>;
```

Notes:

- Use `UNION ALL` unless you explicitly want to remove duplicates (there is a performance penalty).
- In MySQL, you don't need to repeat the first query in the `NOT EXISTS` (or `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN`) logic, if you are using correlation logic.  In other databases, CTEs would simplify the whole thing.
- With proper indexing, this should be fast.

Answer (score -1):

Use left outer join to retain all records in left table and matching records in right table.